# Using insert-many with generics in rust

Tags: mongodb, rust

While writing a wrapper for insert-many, I wanted to add generic T to accept any struct as input of function.

But doing this gives the error "the method `insert_many` exists fro struct mongodb::Collection", but its trait bounds were not satisfied..."

```
pub async fn insert<T>(&self, docs: Vec<T>, col_name: String, options: InsertManyOptions) {
    self.db
        .collection::<T>(&col_name)
        .insert_many(docs, options);
}
```

How should I go forward implementing this, and what is the meaning of this error in this context?

EDIT:

> "T: api::task::_::_serde::Serialize"

This was there, but somehow I got confused because of the weird path it was using instead of the global serde crate.

Comment: If you'd included the error in full, you'd see it tells you: you need to constrain `T: Serialize`.

Comment: Yes, you are right about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics in Rust work different than in C++. While in C++ it's a simple code replacement, in Rust you have to annotate what capabilities the generic has to fulfill. And only if you annotate the capabilities are you allowed to use them inside the function.

In your case, according to the [mongodb::Collection](https://docs.rs/mongodb/latest/mongodb/struct.Collection.html#impl-4) documentation, the function `insert_many` only exists if `T` implements the `Serialize` trait. That means, you have to specify that the generic `T` does so.

```rust
use serde::Serialize;

// ...

pub async fn insert<T>(&self, docs: Vec<T>, col_name: String, options: InsertManyOptions)
where
    T: Serialize,
{
    self.db
        .collection::<T>(&col_name)
        .insert_many(docs, options);
}
```

---

Disclaimer #1: You need to add `serde` as a dependency in your `Cargo.toml`.

Disclaimer #2: Due to the missing context I did not actually test the code.